# OpenSSL compilation for Android x86

Tags: android, openssl, x86

I've been trying to cross-compile OpenSSL for Android x86 for some couple of hours now.
Current OpenSSL version is 1.1.0, but, correct me if I'm wrong, the current OpenSSL documentation does not cover 1.1.0 installation, but only the previous ones. Even if 1.1.0 is clearly stated at the beginning of the installation documentation, and some allusions are done sometimes, I found it not relevant enough to help me step-by-step to install v1.1.0.

I suppose the solution to my issue is trivial, but even so, I couldn't resolve it.
In brief, here is what I've done :

- Downloaded OpenSSL 1.1.0 sources.
- Downloaded a tiny script recommended on several forums (may also be on the official installation doc) to configure some environment variables before installation :
      Available here : https://github.com/rjmangubat23/OpenSSL/blob/master/x86/setenv-android.sh
- Modified it to fit my needs :

  _ANDROID_NDK="android-ndk-r12b"

  _ANDROID_EABI="x86-4.9"

  _ANDROID_API="android-21"
- We also need toolchains for the architecture we want to build Stunnel for.
  I took all toolchains for Android contained in the NDK on AOSP's website :

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html

Mostly used/tried three of them : x86, x86_64, and ARM.

- Configuration went well using this config we can find on the OpenSSL installation tutorial:

  $ ./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp no-hw no-engine --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/$ANDROID_API
- Next step is to make sources using $ make. 
  Here's where I've been stuck, this shows an error :

"*/bin/sh: 1: i686-linux-android-gcc: not found*" as if it was not finding the x86 toolchain.
   This issue happened with every toolchain :

"/bin/sh: 1: i686-linux-android-gcc: not found" when used with x86 toolchain

"/bin/sh: 1: x86_64-linux-android-gcc: not found" when used with x86_64 toolchain

"/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: not found" when used with ARM toolchain

- The issue probably comes from a bad environment variable, but I correcly added toolchains paths to my PATH environment variable.

Hoping a great guy could help me with this. Do not hesitate to ask me further informations.
Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: _"x86-4.6"_ IIRC, NDK r12b doesn't come with GCC 4.6. Have you tried specifying 4.9 instead?

Comment: You were right, I've done a mistake writing this post, but x86-4.9 was correctly set. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @JohnFisherman did you fix it??